# CSS Drop down menu styling overlapping

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

**Q:** Would anyone know how to style the sub-menu on my website so it doesn't over-lap as it does now?

I have tied to do it within the CSS but all the submenus move across, rather than just the child menus.

> cherwelluk.com

Roll-over Windows and try and select timber alternatives.

```
.nav.navbar-nav li ul.sub-menu li a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0QBE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this CSS rule to move the sub-sub menu to the right of the sub menu:

```
.nav.navbar-nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
    left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Would you know what code I need to add to the CSS so that it aligns correctly on a mobile and ipad?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS.

```
.sub-menu{margin-left:10px}
```